# How to Implement Cassandra Counter Columns with phantom-dsl?

Tags: scala, cassandra-2.0, phantom-dsl

This is an extension to this question:

[How to increment Cassandra Counter Column with phantom-dsl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236128/how-to-increment-cassandra-counter-column-with-phantom-dsl)

This question has also been asked [here](https://github.com/thiagoandrade6/cassandra-phantom/issues/7).

In [Thiagos example](https://github.com/thiagoandrade6/cassandra-phantom) the two tables; 'songs' & 'songs_by_artist' both have the same rows but with different partitions (primary keys / clustering columns)

```
CREATE TABLE test.songs (
    song_id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
    album text,
    artist text,
    title text
);

CREATE TABLE test.songs_by_artist (
    artist text,
    song_id timeuuid,
    album text,
    title text,
    PRIMARY KEY (artist, song_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (song_id ASC);
```

This means inserting, updating and deleting across both tables within the [SongsService](https://github.com/thiagoandrade6/cassandra-phantom/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cassandra/phantom/modeling/service/SongsService.scala) works with the same base data / rows.

How would you for example have a table such as 'artist_songs_counts', with columns 'song_id' (K) and 'num_songs' (++) and ensure that 'SongsService' adds corresponding row to each table;  'songs' & 'songs_by_artist'  &  'artist_songs_counts' (where there are different numbers of row but information should be linked, such as the artist info).

```
CREATE TABLE test.artist_songs_counts (
    artist text PRIMARY KEY,
    num_songs counter);
```

Comment: @flavian this may be another one for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SongsService` extends `ProductionDatabaseProvider` that gives to you an object called `database` where you have access to tables under a certain database:

```
/**
    * Find songs by Id
    * @param id
    * @return
    */
  def getSongById(id: UUID): Future[Option[Song]] = {
    database.songsModel.getBySongId(id)
  }
```

Or even better, handling two tables at the same time:

```
  /**
   * Save a song in both tables
   *
   * @param songs
   * @return
   */
  def saveOrUpdate(songs: Song): Future[ResultSet] = {
    for {
      byId <- database.songsModel.store(songs)
      byArtist <- database.songsByArtistsModel.store(songs)
    } yield byArtist
  }
```

Since through a `database` object you can access all tables that belongs to a specific Database, I would implement a counter for artist the following way:

```
def increment(artist: String): Future[ResultSet] = {
  update
    .where(_.artist eqs artist)
    .modify(_.numSongs += 1)
    .future()
}
```

Then the `saveOrUpdate` method could be written as below:

```
def saveOrUpdate(song: Song): Future[ResultSet] = {
    for {
      byId <- database.songsModel.store(songs)
      byArtist <- database.songsByArtistsModel.store(songs)
      counter <- database.artistSongsCounter.increment(song.artist)
    } yield byArtist
  }
```